# How can fetch documents from mongodb that are newer than a specific document? Node / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, notifications

I am trying to create on-page notifications, like facebook.

So when the user first opens the notification tray (clicking on the button on the page), it will load their latest notifications (makes an ajax request to server for the latest notifications, which returns the html of their 8 latest notifications).

But if they open it again later, I need to load all the notifications that came after the newest one that we have on the page.

Is it possible to specify a document ID and then grab all the notifications that came after it, without making a separate request first to figure out that notifications createdOn date?

Or perhaps there is another way?

Comment: I supposed I could store the date in the html and send it back and parse it, seems easier to fail and abuse though

Comment: Yes, the first time the user opens it, it loads the latest ones into the dom. Then I need a way to load newer ones if the user checks it. (I said this above but let me know if somethings not clear)

Comment: it makes a request to the server to get the latest notifications and the server returns html which is then injected onto the page in the notifications tray

Comment: Hopefully that is more clear